# SVN to Git using git svn - keeping git updated

Tags: git, svn, gitlab, migration

I am migrating from SVN to git using the git-svn plugin.

I cloned the SVN repo with history and that worked.  I was able to push into my Gitlab 'main' branch in my new repository.  And when I do a `git svn fetch` I see the changes from my SVN repo.  And doing git log --all shows the revisions.

But nothing I do seems to push the new change up to the git Repo.

git branches (I did not need to migrate any tags or branches other than trunk)

```
~/GitMigration/Blah-Main $ git branch
* main
~/GitMigration/Blah-Main $ git branch -r
  origin/main
  origin/trunk
```

The original push into the git repo main branch I had to do a -f but even that doesnt seem to do anything

```
~/GitMigration/Blah-Main $ git branch -a
* main
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/trunk
~/GitMigration/Blah-Main $

~/GitMigration/Org-Main $ git push origin main
Everything up-to-date

svn-remote.svn.url=https://svn.com/Org/svn
svn-remote.svn.fetch=Org/trunk:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
svn-remote.svn.branches=Org/branches/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
svn-remote.svn.tags=Org/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
svn.authorsfile=/Users/user/GitMigration/authors.txt
remote.origin.url=https://gitlab.com/org/org-main.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
```

Comment: How (what command) are you using to push the branch into the remote git repo?

Comment: and also, what is the svn branch in `git branch -r`? Maybe we need the output of `git branch -a`

Comment: what is the svn branch? I might be wrong but I _think_ that the svn branch should show up as a remote branch. Is it `origin/trunk`? Well... that's funky, but _possible_ (having the svn remote with the same name as the _real_ git remote). If that is the case, then you should run `git push origin origin/trunk:main`.... at it _looks_ funky because you are using `origin` for both the svn repo and the (remote) git repo.

Comment: @eftshift0 Wow!  That worked, I would have never figured that out.  Could you make your comment an answer and maybe add a little explanation (and/or fix) so I can upvote and give you the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are pushing `main` (local `main`), which is not the right branch to push. Given that your svn branch is (apparently) `origin/trunk`, you should run this to have it show up in `origin/main`:

```
git push origin origin/trunk:main
```

The trick to understand here is that to git, it's all about commits.... and branches are just *pointers* to commits. The svn branch is *not* (local) `main`, it's `origin/trunk`, so, after running `git svn fetch` to sync up, what has moved is `origin/trunk` and so we need to push that *commit* to `origin/main`... hence the command I used there (breaking up that command, it is: `git push <some-remote> <some-commit>:<remote-branch>`).

## Side note:

It bugs be a little bit that you set `git-svn` to map the svn branch to `origin`, should probably keep the svn repo and the *real* git repo as different remotes (so that the svn branch could show up as `svn/trunk`, for example)... if that were the case, after `git svn fetch`, you would run:

```
git push origin svn/trunk:main
```

Which looks *a lot* better *but*, as we can see, it's possible to keep it the way you have it.

Comment: Thanks, so I can rename the svn remote to "fix" this?

Comment: I have no experience renaming so can't really tell in advance.

Comment: No worries, already been a big help - added my git config to the question if that helps at all